# how to display flash message when an item is selected from options in flask

Tags: python, sorting, flask, filter, jinja2

Here is an html or Jinja form

```
<form role="search" class="navbar-form nav-item" action="filter" method="GET">
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-6" name="myselect" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option value="new" selected> New</option>
        <option value="old">Old</option>
        <option value="randow">Random</option>
        <option value="more">More Videos</option>
        <option value="less">Less Videos</option>
      </select>
    </div>

        <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-6" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option value="all course">All Courses</option>
        <option value="free">Free Courses</option>
        <option value="all price">Price - All</option>
        <option value="lowest">Price - Lowest</option>
        <option value="highest">Price - Highest</option>

      </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

now how can i create a flask code/view to flash message when any of the options is selected? If I can get this logic right, I can equally use this logic to create a filter system to sort database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any message is flashed from the flask app, then that can easily be displayed on HTML using Jinja. Just paste the following code where you want flash messages to be displayed; preferably right after the body starts.

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="alert alert-info">
       {{ message }}

     </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

the above code works well if there are flash messages (one of more), and no error if there aren't. Note

> class="alert alert-info"

is css formating of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to check whether flash messages actually exist before displaying them. If the messages are present, then they can be displayed; if not, then nothing will be displayed.

In flask (wherever you want to show the flashed messages) you can do this:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-info" role = "alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor%}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

The alerts can be modified to your preference, from examples within the [flask-bootstrap framework](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/alerts/).